# What's an example of a function that is continuous at $0$ but is not second-differentable at $0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

What's an example of a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ where $f$ is continuous at $0$ but is not second-differentable at $0$?

Comment: Take a function $f$ which is continuous but not differentiable at $0$, for example, $f(x)=|x|$

Comment: That's not how you spell "beginner".

Answer (score 2):

Take$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2&\text{ if }x\geqslant0\\-x^2&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=|x|$ is continuous at $0$ but is not differentable at $0$ so  not second-differentable at $0$

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you mean 1 time differentiable at 0, then let consider

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2&\text{ if }x\geqslant0\\0&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

thus

$$f’(x)=\begin{cases}2x&\text{ if }x\geqslant0\\0&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

and $f’’(0)$ is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$ f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2&x\in\Bbb Q\\0&x\notin \Bbb Q\end{cases}$$

Then $f$ is continuous at $0$ (but nowhere else), and is differentiable at $0$ (with $f'(0)=0$) but nowhere else; consequently, $f$ is nowhere twice differentiable.

Comment: You want to change $x^2$ to $x,$ because $f''(0)$ exists and equals $0$ for your example. I first thought that you pretty much gave the most pathological such example (when corrected), but then it occurred to me how to get some examples that are even more pathological. Let $f(x)$ be a Sierpinski-Zygmund function, or a nonlinear solution to the Cauchy functional equation, and consider $x \cdot \arctan f(x).$